# MVC application using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I developed some Spring MVC Application about 2-3 years ago. I need to develop another web application and I thought about using Spring MVC.
I have to build an application using JSP, Spring Controller and Spring Service (and Hibernate), and deploy it in a WildFly Application Server.

I started Eclipse Mars with STS plugin and the way I used to develop Spring MVC application is now stated as "legacy":

[image: snap 1]

This is exactly the way I used to create the filesytem:

[image]

Is MVC Spring and old technology? Do I have to migrate to another Spring library?

Comment: XML configuration is legacy. Javaconfig is now recommended. Further, Spring Boot is now the preferred approach.

Comment: I'm checking it and for sure I will study it. Just to know if I undestood you: Spring Boot let you create and run application, but you can also configure the project to be deployed on an AS (via WEB-INF, META-INF etc...using the DispatcherServlet). If I need to configure something (like Hibernate, I suppose), I can do it via .properties files, correct?

Comment: No properties files. All programmatic. By default Boot deploys an embedded web server, it can easily be configured (again, programmatically) to deploy on a servlet container.